# How to sort numbers into 1,2,3,4,...,22 instead of 1,10,11,..,2,20,21,22 in script shell?

Tags: bash, shell

Right now i have

```
listOfFiles = a list of array name like version1, version2,..,version22 // originally sql file
FILES=()
for s in $listOfFiles; 
do FILES+=($s);
done
# sort the array into ascending order
Sorted=($(echo ${FILES[*]}| tr " " "\n" | sort -n))
for s in "${Sorted[@]}";
# check existing script files version
do  a=$(tr -cd 0-9 <<<"$s");   
if [ $a -gt $formerVersion ]; 
    then $(mysql ...//execute the sql);
```

which executes in order of version1,version10,version11,..,version2,version20,version21,version22, not version1,version2,version3,...version22 as expected

Comment: Convert them to numbers first then sort, rather than sorting as strings

Comment: @retsehG Actually sort -n should work. Are you sure you are using it?

Comment: It would help to see the actual value of `$FILES`. Are the elements filenames? Are the names *just* numbers, or are the numbers a suffix (`foo1`, `foo2`, ...)?

Comment: We really need a [mcve] here so the question contains enough to let others reproduce the problem directly.

Comment: That said, note that there's a lot that's buggy with the existing implementation -- if your filenames contained whitespace, or your lines being sorted had non-numeric columns (particularly with glob characters in them), you'd have a bad time with this code.

Comment: (Also, filenames are allowed to contain newline characters, so the ideal format to use to represent a list of filenames in a stream of characters is delimited by NULs, not newlines or spaces).

Comment: FILES is a list of array name like version1, version2,..,version22

Comment: Yes i am sure i have used sort -n

Comment: And there is no white space in filenames

Comment: Is it still possible to rename the resp. files? (To come around problems like you have, I'm usually enumerate files in this case with the appropriate number of leading zeros.)

Comment: Please update your question to show us real code, not pseudo-code. That should include an actual literal list of file names, and showing us how `$list` is set. Someone should be able to copy-and-paste the code from your question and run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soleve it by using:

```
sort -n -k 2 -t n
```

Reference page:
https://www.computerhope.com/unix/usort.htm

Comment: your `-t v`, needs to be `-t n` from what you showed us.  *shrug*

Comment: Yes, i am gonna change it.

Answer (score 0):

It's the piping that is getting you.  Also, no need for the tr.

```
Sorted=($(sort -nk2 -t n <( echo ${FILES[@]}|tr " " "\n")))
```

edit: the k 8 doesn't work, b/c it looks at each characters a field, so 2, will never be compared to 11.  This works, as long as your filenames all have an 'n' right before their version numbers.

Comment: Sorry, just described wrongly.. FILES is a string of concatenation of all the file names. Editted the question again just now. And that is why i used tr..